# Retrieve data from array in another function

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to retrieve the data set in an array in one function, in a different function. I appended the data i want into the OtherUserArray in the
createNewConversation function. However when i try the retrieve this data in the sendMessage function, it prints an empty array.

```
import MessageKit
import InputBarAccessoryView
import FirebaseAuth
import Firebase
import Foundation


final class DatabaseManager {

static let shared = DatabaseManager()

var foundOtherUser:String?

var OtherUserArray = [String]()

}

extension DatabaseManager {

// create a new conversation with target user, uid and first sent message
public func createNewConversation(with otherUserUid: String, name: String, firstMessage: Message, completion: @escaping(Bool) -> Void) {
    
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let CurrentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    defaults.set(CurrentUser, forKey: "uid")
    
    guard let currentUid = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "uid"), let currentName = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "usersFullname") else {
        return
    }
   
    let messageDate = firstMessage.sentDate
    
    let dateString = MessageViewController.dateFormatter.string(from: messageDate)
    
    var message = ""
    
    let conversationId = firstMessage.messageId
    
    let newConversationData: [String:Any] = [
    "id": conversationId,
    "other_user-uid": otherUserUid,
        "name": name,
    "latest-message": [
        "date": dateString,
        "message": message,
        "is-read": false
      ]
    ]
    
    // save other user uid to global var
    
    OtherUserArray.append(otherUserUid)

    }
}
}

 public func sendMessage(to conversation: String, name: String, newMessage: Message, completion: @escaping(Bool) -> Void) {
    
    // update the latest message
    print(self.OtherUserArray)

}
```

Comment: What is the DatabaseManager class? Is it part of Firebase's API or did you create it?

Comment: No i created it myself

Comment: Can you add the code for it please?

Comment: i have added to complete code

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not **where** you access `self.OtherUserArray`, but when you access it.

Data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously, while the rest of you code typically runs synchronously. By the time the `print(self.OtherUserArray)` in your `sendMessage`  runs, the `OtherUserArray.append(otherUserUid)` hasn't been executed yet, so the array in empty. You can most easily verify this by running the code in a debugger and setting breakpoints on those like, or by adding `print` statements and checking the order of their output.

For examples of this, as well as how to solve the problem, see these previous questions:

- [Why I couldn't assign fetched values from Firestore to an array in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52244924/why-i-couldnt-assign-fetched-values-from-firestore-to-an-array-in-swift/52245358#52245358)
- [Is Firebase getDocument run line by line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61561868/is-firebase-getdocument-run-line-by-line/61564335#61564335)
- [Storing asynchronous Cloud Firestore query results in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59482689/storing-asynchronous-cloud-firestore-query-results-in-swift/59482729#59482729)
- [How do I save data from cloud firestore to a variable in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63062031/how-do-i-save-data-from-cloud-firestore-to-a-variable-in-swift/63064140#63064140)
- [Why are print statements not executing in correct order?? Am I crazy or is Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59699137/why-are-print-statements-not-executing-in-correct-order-am-i-crazy-or-is-xcode/59699211#59699211)
- [Get all documents at once in a completion handler with getDocuments in Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60125604/get-all-documents-at-once-in-a-completion-handler-with-getdocuments-in-firestore/60128069#60128069)